# JS scrollbar not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this script that would drag through a series of `<li>` that are organized by years on a timeline. However, I cannot drag horizontally through the page. Is there a better hay of doing this? What could be wrong?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    /* This code is executed after the DOM has been completely loaded */
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* This code is executed after the DOM has been completely loaded */

    /* The number of event sections / years with events */
    var tot=$('.event').length;

    $('.eventList li').click(function(e){
            showWindow('<div>'+$(this).find('div.content').html()+'</div>');
    });

    /* Each event section is 320 px wide */
    var timelineWidth = 320*tot;
    var screenWidth = $(document).width();

    $('#timelineScroll').width(timelineWidth);

    /* If the timeline is wider than the screen show the slider: */
    if(timelineWidth > screenWidth)
    {
        $('#scroll,#slider').show();
        $('#centered,#slider').width(120*tot);

        /* Making the scrollbar draggable: */
        $('#bar').width((120/320)*screenWidth).draggable({

            containment: 'parent',
            drag: function(e, ui) {

                if(!this.elem)
                {
                    /* This section is executed only the first time the function is run for performance */

                    this.elem = $('#timelineScroll');

                    /* The difference between the slider's width and its container: */
                    this.maxSlide = ui.helper.parent().width()-ui.helper.width();

                    /* The difference between the timeline's width and its container */
                    this.cWidth = this.elem.width()-this.elem.parent().width();
                    this.highlight = $('#highlight');
                }

                /* Translating each movement of the slider to the timeline: */
                this.elem.css({marginLeft:'-'+((ui.position.left/this.maxSlide)*this.cWidth)+'px'});

                /* Moving the highlight: */
                this.highlight.css('left',ui.position.left)
            }
        });

        $('#highlight').width((120/320)*screenWidth-3);
    }

});
```

```css
body,h1,h2,h3,p,quote,small,form,input,ul,li,ol,label{
 /* Simple page reset */
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

body{
 /* Setting default text color, background and a font stack */
 color:#555555;
 font-size:0.825em;
 background: #fcfcfc;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.event{
 /* Contains the event header and body list */
 float:left;
 padding:4px;
 text-align:left;
 width:300px;
 margin:0 5px 50px;
}

.eventList li{
 /* The individual events */
 background:#F4F4F4;
 border:1px solid #EEEEEE;
 list-style:none;
 margin:5px;
 padding:4px 7px;
 
 /* CSS3 rounded corners */
 -moz-border-radius:4px;
 -webkit-border-radius:4px;
 border-radius:4px;
}

.eventList li:hover{
 /* The hover state: */
 cursor:pointer;
 background:#E6F8FF;
 border:1px solid #D4E6EE;
 color:#548DA5;
}

li span{
 /* The event icon */
 display:block;
 float:left;
 height:16px;
 margin-right:5px;
 width:16px;
}

/* Individual background images for each type of event: */

li.news span.icon {  background:url(img/icons/newspaper.png) no-repeat; }
li.image span.icon {  background:url(img/icons/camera.png) no-repeat; }
li.milestone span.icon {  background:url(img/icons/chart.png) no-repeat; }

div.content{
 /* This div contains additional data for the content */
 display:none;
}

.eventHeading{
 /* The colorful year headings at the top */
 font-size:2em;
 margin:-5px -5px 10px;
 padding:2px 5px;
 text-align:center;
}

/* Three color styles for the headings: */

.eventHeading.chreme{
 background:#FBF7F0;
 border:1px solid #EEE4D4;
 color:#A78B5F;
}

.eventHeading.blue{
 background:#E6F8FF;
 border:1px solid #D4E6EE;
 color:#548DA5;
}

.eventHeading.green{
 background:#E6FFDF none repeat scroll 0 0;
 border:1px solid #C9E6C1;
 color:#6EA85F;
}

#timelineLimiter{
 /* Hides the overflowing timeline */
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
 padding-top:10px;
 margin:40px 0;
}

#scroll{
 /* The small timeline below the main one. Hidden here and shown by jQuery if JS is enabled: */
 display:none;
 height:30px;

 background:#F5F5F5;
 border:1px solid #EEEEEE;
 color:#999999;
}

.scrollPoints{
 /* The individual years */
 float:left;
 font-size:1.4em;
 padding:4px 10px;
 text-align:center;
 width:100px;
 
 position:relative;
 z-index:10;
}

#centered{
 /* Centers the years, width is assigned by jQuery */
 margin:0 auto;
 position:relative;
}

#slider{
 /* Holds the scroll bar */
 margin:10px auto;
 height:25px;
 display:none;
}

#bar{
 /* The scroll bar */
 background:url(img/slider_center.png) repeat-x center center;
 height:25px;
 cursor:pointer;
}

#barLeft{
 background:transparent url(img/slider.png) no-repeat scroll left center;
 height:25px;
 width:20px;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 position:absolute;
}

#barRight{
 background:transparent url(img/slider.png) no-repeat scroll right center;
 height:25px;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 width:20px;
}

#overlay{
 /* The overlay that darkens the page when an event is clicked */
 position:absolute;
 z-index:10;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 background-color:#222222;
}

#windowBox{
 /* Shows details about the event on click */
 position:absolute;
 z-index:20;
 background-color:#fcfcfc;
 padding:10px;
 border:2px solid #666666;
 overflow:auto;
}

#titleDiv{
 /* The title of the windowBox */
 background:#F5F5F5;
 border:1px solid #EEEEEE;
 color:#AAAAAA;
 font-size:1.5em;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 padding:5px 10px;
}

#date{
 /* The date on the bottom of the windowBox */
 bottom:20px;
 color:#999999;
 font-size:0.8em;
 font-style:italic;
 position:absolute;
 right:15px;
 padding:2px;
 background:#FCFCFC;
}

#highlight{
 /* The blue highlight that moves with the scroll bar */
 height:30px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:0;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 
 background:#E6F8FF;
 border:1px solid #D4E6EE;
 border-width:0 1px;
}

.clear{
 clear:both;
}

/* The styles below are only necessary for the demo page */

h1{
 background:#F4F4F4;
 border-bottom:1px solid #EEEEEE;
 font-family:"Myriad Pro",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 font-size:20px;
 font-weight:normal;
 margin-bottom:15px;
 padding:15px;
 text-align:center;
}

h2 {
 font-family:"Myriad Pro",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 font-size:12px;
 font-weight:normal;
 padding-right:40px;
 position:relative;
 right:0;
 text-align:right;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 top:-48px;
}

a, a:visited {
 color:#0196e3;
 text-decoration:none;
 outline:none;
}

a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline;
}

p.tutInfo{
 /* The tutorial info on the bottom of the page */
 padding:10px 0;
 text-align:center;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0px;
 background:#F4F4F4;
 border-top:1px solid #EEEEEE;
 width:100%;
}
/*
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
*/
/* 
    Created on : Feb 18, 2017, 12:11:54 PM
    Author     : Rodrigo
*/
```

```html
<div id="timelineLimiter"> <!-- Hides the overflowing timelineScroll div -->
     <div id="timelineScroll"> <!-- Contains the timeline and expands to fit -->

  
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading green">Aug 2015</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Segueta 24 dientes paquete 10 unidades 3906-300...</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">0</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Segueta 24 dientes paquete 10 unidades 3906-300...</div>
     <div class="date">August 6, 2015</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>0</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading blue">Nov 2016</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Guantes Hilaza Neon Puntos PVC 2 Caras</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">280,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Guantes Hilaza Neon Puntos PVC 2 Caras</div>
     <div class="date">November 2, 2016</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>280,000</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading chreme">Feb 2017</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Espatula Extra Ancha</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">42</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Espatula Extra Ancha</div>
     <div class="date">February 1, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Parasol Lateral 3 m Blanco</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">28</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Parasol Lateral 3 m Blanco</div>
     <div class="date">February 1, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Enfriadores Azul</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">1,800,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Enfriadores Azul</div>
     <div class="date">February 2, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Alambre #8 100 metros amarillo Conectores y Cables</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">0</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Alambre #8 100 metros amarillo Conectores y Cables</div>
     <div class="date">February 2, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Vitaperico1 Kg</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">72</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Vitaperico1 Kg</div>
     <div class="date">February 13, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Varilla 5/8 pulgada x 6 metros cuadrada</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">6,800,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Varilla 5/8 pulgada x 6 metros cuadrada</div>
     <div class="date">February 17, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Escobilla Limpiafondo</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">1,240,000,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Escobilla Limpiafondo</div>
     <div class="date">February 23, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>1,248,600,142</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading green">Apr 2017</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Asoleadora Curva Chocolate</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">750,000,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Asoleadora Curva Chocolate</div>
     <div class="date">April 21, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>750,000,000</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading blue">Mar 2018</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Llanta 275/55 Rin 20 111S CC LX20</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">400</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Llanta 275/55 Rin 20 111S CC LX20</div>
     <div class="date">March 1, 2018</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>400</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading chreme">Feb 2019</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Ladrillo hor 3 huecos 9x20x80 9.5k 6.25und/m2</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">336,002,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Ladrillo hor 3 huecos 9x20x80 9.5k 6.25und/m2</div>
     <div class="date">February 1, 2019</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>336,001,664</h1></ul></div>     
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="scroll"> <!-- The year time line -->
            <div id="centered"> <!-- Sized by jQuery to fit all the years -->
             <div id="highlight"></div> <!-- The light blue highlight shown behind the years -->
             <div class="scrollPoints">Aug 2015</div><div class="scrollPoints">Nov 2016</div><div class="scrollPoints">Feb 2017</div><div class="scrollPoints">Apr 2017</div><div class="scrollPoints">Mar 2018</div><div class="scrollPoints">Feb 2019</div> <!-- This PHP variable holds the years that have events -->
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="slider"> <!-- The slider container -->
         <div id="bar"> <!-- The bar that can be dragged -->
             <div id="barLeft"></div>  <!-- Left arrow of the bar -->
                <div id="barRight"></div>  <!-- Right arrow, both are styled with CSS -->
          </div>
        </div>
        
    </div> 

   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
    /* The number of event sections / years with events */
    var tot=$('.event').length;

    $('.eventList li').click(function(e){
            showWindow('<div>'+$(this).find('div.content').html()+'</div>');
    });

    /* Each event section is 320 px wide */
    var timelineWidth = 320*tot;
    var screenWidth = $(document).width();

    $('#timelineScroll').width(timelineWidth);

    /* If the timeline is wider than the screen show the slider: */
    if(timelineWidth > screenWidth)
    {
        $('#scroll,#slider').show();
        $('#centered,#slider').width(120*tot);

        /* Making the scrollbar draggable: */
        $('#bar').width((120/320)*screenWidth).draggable({

            containment: 'parent',
            drag: function(e, ui) {

                if(!this.elem)
                {
                    /* This section is executed only the first time the function is run for performance */

                    this.elem = $('#timelineScroll');

                    /* The difference between the slider's width and its container: */
                    this.maxSlide = ui.helper.parent().width()-ui.helper.width();

                    /* The difference between the timeline's width and its container */
                    this.cWidth = this.elem.width()-this.elem.parent().width();
                    this.highlight = $('#highlight');
                }

                /* Translating each movement of the slider to the timeline: */
                this.elem.css({marginLeft:'-'+((ui.position.left/this.maxSlide)*this.cWidth)+'px'});

                /* Moving the highlight: */
                this.highlight.css('left',ui.position.left)
            }
        });

        $('#highlight').width((120/320)*screenWidth-3);
    }

});
```

Why could be causing the issue?

Comment: Please create a working example by clicking Ctrl+M while you are writing/editing your question's content.

Comment: Just added all the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a position issue with your #bar.
I didn't have time to think too much to find out how to solve it properly but you would find the solution easier if you know where the problem is.

Add these styles to #bar and check.

```
background: rgba(255,0,0,0.2); /* make it partially visible to track */
z-index:999;  /* make it on top of others */
margin-top: -40px;  /* workaround for y positioning problem */
```

Here is the code that the workaround has been applied :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* This code is executed after the DOM has been completely loaded */

    /* The number of event sections / years with events */
    var tot=$('.event').length;

    $('.eventList li').click(function(e){
            showWindow('<div>'+$(this).find('div.content').html()+'</div>');
    });

    /* Each event section is 320 px wide */
    var timelineWidth = 320*tot;
    var screenWidth = $(document).width();

    $('#timelineScroll').width(timelineWidth);

    /* If the timeline is wider than the screen show the slider: */
    if(timelineWidth > screenWidth)
    {
        $('#scroll,#slider').show();
        $('#centered,#slider').width(120*tot);

        /* Making the scrollbar draggable: */
        $('#bar').width((120/320)*screenWidth).draggable({

            containment: 'parent',
            drag: function(e, ui) {

                if(!this.elem)
                {
                    /* This section is executed only the first time the function is run for performance */

                    this.elem = $('#timelineScroll');

                    /* The difference between the slider's width and its container: */
                    this.maxSlide = ui.helper.parent().width()-ui.helper.width();

                    /* The difference between the timeline's width and its container */
                    this.cWidth = this.elem.width()-this.elem.parent().width();
                    this.highlight = $('#highlight');
                }

                /* Translating each movement of the slider to the timeline: */
                this.elem.css({marginLeft:'-'+((ui.position.left/this.maxSlide)*this.cWidth)+'px'});

                /* Moving the highlight: */
                this.highlight.css('left',ui.position.left)
            }
        });

        $('#highlight').width((120/320)*screenWidth-3);
    }

});
```

```css
body,h1,h2,h3,p,quote,small,form,input,ul,li,ol,label{
 /* Simple page reset */
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

body{
 /* Setting default text color, background and a font stack */
 color:#555555;
 font-size:0.825em;
 background: #fcfcfc;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.event{
 /* Contains the event header and body list */
 float:left;
 padding:4px;
 text-align:left;
 width:300px;
 margin:0 5px 50px;
}

.eventList li{
 /* The individual events */
 background:#F4F4F4;
 border:1px solid #EEEEEE;
 list-style:none;
 margin:5px;
 padding:4px 7px;
 
 /* CSS3 rounded corners */
 -moz-border-radius:4px;
 -webkit-border-radius:4px;
 border-radius:4px;
}

.eventList li:hover{
 /* The hover state: */
 cursor:pointer;
 background:#E6F8FF;
 border:1px solid #D4E6EE;
 color:#548DA5;
}

li span{
 /* The event icon */
 display:block;
 float:left;
 height:16px;
 margin-right:5px;
 width:16px;
}

/* Individual background images for each type of event: */

li.news span.icon {  background:url(img/icons/newspaper.png) no-repeat; }
li.image span.icon {  background:url(img/icons/camera.png) no-repeat; }
li.milestone span.icon {  background:url(img/icons/chart.png) no-repeat; }

div.content{
 /* This div contains additional data for the content */
 display:none;
}

.eventHeading{
 /* The colorful year headings at the top */
 font-size:2em;
 margin:-5px -5px 10px;
 padding:2px 5px;
 text-align:center;
}

/* Three color styles for the headings: */

.eventHeading.chreme{
 background:#FBF7F0;
 border:1px solid #EEE4D4;
 color:#A78B5F;
}

.eventHeading.blue{
 background:#E6F8FF;
 border:1px solid #D4E6EE;
 color:#548DA5;
}

.eventHeading.green{
 background:#E6FFDF none repeat scroll 0 0;
 border:1px solid #C9E6C1;
 color:#6EA85F;
}

#timelineLimiter{
 /* Hides the overflowing timeline */
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
 padding-top:10px;
 margin:40px 0;
}

#scroll{
 /* The small timeline below the main one. Hidden here and shown by jQuery if JS is enabled: */
 display:none;
 height:30px;

 background:#F5F5F5;
 border:1px solid #EEEEEE;
 color:#999999;
}

.scrollPoints{
 /* The individual years */
 float:left;
 font-size:1.4em;
 padding:4px 10px;
 text-align:center;
 width:100px;
 
 position:relative;
 z-index:10;
}

#centered{
 /* Centers the years, width is assigned by jQuery */
 margin:0 auto;
 position:relative;
}

#slider{
 /* Holds the scroll bar */
 margin:10px auto;
 height:25px;
 display:none;
}

#bar{
 /* The scroll bar */
 background:url(img/slider_center.png) repeat-x center center;
 height:25px;
 cursor:pointer;

  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.2); /* make it partially visible to track */
  z-index:999;  /* make it on top of others */
  margin-top: -40px;  /* workaround for y positioning problem */  

}

#barLeft{
 background:transparent url(img/slider.png) no-repeat scroll left center;
 height:25px;
 width:20px;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 position:absolute;
}

#barRight{
 background:transparent url(img/slider.png) no-repeat scroll right center;
 height:25px;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 width:20px;
}

#overlay{
 /* The overlay that darkens the page when an event is clicked */
 position:absolute;
 z-index:10;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 background-color:#222222;
}

#windowBox{
 /* Shows details about the event on click */
 position:absolute;
 z-index:20;
 background-color:#fcfcfc;
 padding:10px;
 border:2px solid #666666;
 overflow:auto;
}

#titleDiv{
 /* The title of the windowBox */
 background:#F5F5F5;
 border:1px solid #EEEEEE;
 color:#AAAAAA;
 font-size:1.5em;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 padding:5px 10px;
}

#date{
 /* The date on the bottom of the windowBox */
 bottom:20px;
 color:#999999;
 font-size:0.8em;
 font-style:italic;
 position:absolute;
 right:15px;
 padding:2px;
 background:#FCFCFC;
}

#highlight{
 /* The blue highlight that moves with the scroll bar */
 height:30px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:0;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 
 background:#E6F8FF;
 border:1px solid #D4E6EE;
 border-width:0 1px;
}

.clear{
 clear:both;
}

/* The styles below are only necessary for the demo page */

h1{
 background:#F4F4F4;
 border-bottom:1px solid #EEEEEE;
 font-family:"Myriad Pro",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 font-size:20px;
 font-weight:normal;
 margin-bottom:15px;
 padding:15px;
 text-align:center;
}

h2 {
 font-family:"Myriad Pro",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 font-size:12px;
 font-weight:normal;
 padding-right:40px;
 position:relative;
 right:0;
 text-align:right;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 top:-48px;
}

a, a:visited {
 color:#0196e3;
 text-decoration:none;
 outline:none;
}

a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline;
}

p.tutInfo{
 /* The tutorial info on the bottom of the page */
 padding:10px 0;
 text-align:center;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0px;
 background:#F4F4F4;
 border-top:1px solid #EEEEEE;
 width:100%;
}
/*
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
*/
/* 
    Created on : Feb 18, 2017, 12:11:54 PM
    Author     : Rodrigo
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="timelineLimiter"> <!-- Hides the overflowing timelineScroll div -->
     <div id="timelineScroll"> <!-- Contains the timeline and expands to fit -->

  
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading green">Aug 2015</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Segueta 24 dientes paquete 10 unidades 3906-300...</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">0</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Segueta 24 dientes paquete 10 unidades 3906-300...</div>
     <div class="date">August 6, 2015</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>0</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading blue">Nov 2016</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Guantes Hilaza Neon Puntos PVC 2 Caras</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">280,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Guantes Hilaza Neon Puntos PVC 2 Caras</div>
     <div class="date">November 2, 2016</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>280,000</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading chreme">Feb 2017</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Espatula Extra Ancha</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">42</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Espatula Extra Ancha</div>
     <div class="date">February 1, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Parasol Lateral 3 m Blanco</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">28</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Parasol Lateral 3 m Blanco</div>
     <div class="date">February 1, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Enfriadores Azul</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">1,800,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Enfriadores Azul</div>
     <div class="date">February 2, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Alambre #8 100 metros amarillo Conectores y Cables</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">0</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Alambre #8 100 metros amarillo Conectores y Cables</div>
     <div class="date">February 2, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Vitaperico1 Kg</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">72</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Vitaperico1 Kg</div>
     <div class="date">February 13, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Varilla 5/8 pulgada x 6 metros cuadrada</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">6,800,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Varilla 5/8 pulgada x 6 metros cuadrada</div>
     <div class="date">February 17, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Escobilla Limpiafondo</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">1,240,000,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Escobilla Limpiafondo</div>
     <div class="date">February 23, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>1,248,600,142</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading green">Apr 2017</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Asoleadora Curva Chocolate</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">750,000,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Asoleadora Curva Chocolate</div>
     <div class="date">April 21, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>750,000,000</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading blue">Mar 2018</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Llanta 275/55 Rin 20 111S CC LX20</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">400</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Llanta 275/55 Rin 20 111S CC LX20</div>
     <div class="date">March 1, 2018</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>400</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading chreme">Feb 2019</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Ladrillo hor 3 huecos 9x20x80 9.5k 6.25und/m2</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">336,002,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Ladrillo hor 3 huecos 9x20x80 9.5k 6.25und/m2</div>
     <div class="date">February 1, 2019</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>336,001,664</h1></ul></div>     
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="scroll"> <!-- The year time line -->
            <div id="centered"> <!-- Sized by jQuery to fit all the years -->
             <div id="highlight"></div> <!-- The light blue highlight shown behind the years -->
             <div class="scrollPoints">Aug 2015</div><div class="scrollPoints">Nov 2016</div><div class="scrollPoints">Feb 2017</div><div class="scrollPoints">Apr 2017</div><div class="scrollPoints">Mar 2018</div><div class="scrollPoints">Feb 2019</div> <!-- This PHP variable holds the years that have events -->
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="slider"> <!-- The slider container -->
         <div id="bar"> <!-- The bar that can be dragged -->
             <div id="barLeft"></div>  <!-- Left arrow of the bar -->
                <div id="barRight"></div>  <!-- Right arrow, both are styled with CSS -->
          </div>
        </div>
        
    </div> 

   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Still is not aligning but at least I found why it wasnt working!